# ArrayAdapter: Change resource depending on item (Android)

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I'm creating a sort of messaging activity inside my app and I'm using a customed ArrayAdapter to display the items in the ListView. I want to make them go on the right or left depending on the fact that they are received or sent (like Whatsapp or any other messaging app). I tried the following code but it doesn't always display them with the right resource:

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Messages>{
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private int mResource;
private String username;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param context     The current context.
 * @param resource    The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when
 *                    instantiating views.
 * @param messages The objects to represent in the ListView.
 */
public MessagesAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Messages> messages, String username )
{
    super( context, resource, messages );
    mResource = 0;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    this.username = username;
}

@Override
public Messages getItem(int position) {
    return super.getItem(getCount() - position - 1);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
{
    Messages item = getItem( position );

    if (item.getSendername().contentEquals(username)){
        mResource = R.layout.message_right;
        Log.w("Messages", "TRUE" );

    } else {
        mResource = R.layout.message_left;
        Log.w("Messages", "FALSE" );
    }

    View view = convertView == null ? mInflater.inflate( mResource, parent, false ) : convertView;

    TextView txtMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.txtMessage );
    txtMessage.setText( item.getTextmess() );

    return view;
}
```

It actually prints the messages 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' at the right time but, still, sometimes it displays the message using the wrong resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when you check if `convertView` is null, if true you inflate the resource you want, but if not, you just reuse the previous view, which might not be the one with the correct resource.

The issue is in the `false` section of this ternary line:

```
View view = convertView == null ? mInflater.inflate( mResource, parent, false ) : convertView;
```

When it's false, it doesn't take your `mResource` into consideration from when you check the username.

You would want to check if you need to change the resource of `convertView` or perhaps skip even checking if `convertView` is null and just inflate a new view every time.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this: **Adapter**

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Messages> arrayList;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

String username;

public MessagesAdapter(Context context, List<Messages> arrayList, String username) {
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.username = username;
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Messages getItem(int position) {
    return arrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (arrayList.get(position).getSendername().contentEquals(username)){
        return 0;

    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {

        case 0:
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.left, null);
                convertView.setTag(new ViewHolderLeft(convertView));
            }

            initializeViews((Messages) getItem(position), (ViewHolderLeft) convertView.getTag(), position);
            break;
        case 1:

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rigt, null);
                convertView.setTag(new ViewHolderRight(convertView));
            }

            initializeViews((Messages) getItem(position), (ViewHolderRight) convertView.getTag(), position);

            break;
    }
    return convertView;


}

private void initializeViews(Messages item, ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.leftTv.setText(item.getLeft());

}

private void initializeViews(Messages item, ViewHolderRight holder, int position) {
    holder.rightTv.setText(item.getRight());
}

protected class ViewHolderLeft {

    private TextView leftTv;

    public ViewHolderLeft(View view) {
        leftTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.left_tv);
    }
}

protected class ViewHolderRight {

    private TextView rightTv;

    public ViewHolderRight(View view) {
        rightTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.right_tv);
    }
}


}
```